# NavigationController on TabBarItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

i have a tabBarController with 3 items.

In my first view in my first item of my tabBar i have a tableview and a navigationController.

how to go in the second item of my tabBar when i push 1 row in my tableview in the fist item of my tabBar?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


Second *two = [[Second alloc] initWithNibName:@"Second" bundle:nil];


[self.navigationController pushViewController:two animated:YES];

[two release];
```

thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the selectedIndex property on the UITabBarController. More information can be found in the [UITabBarController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

or use

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Note that the indices start at 0, so the second tab is at index 1.

Comment: ok if i do that nothing change:                                                            - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 Second *two = [[Second alloc] initWithNibName:@"Second" bundle:nil];
 chatView.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1 ; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:two animated:YES];
[two release];

Comment: @XcodeMania: I cannot read unformatted code. Well, I can with considerable patience, but please format code as code if you wish me to read it. Also, you're not calling it correctly. See my edits above.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good practice to automatically select a *tabBarItem* when a view controller is pushed into a navigation controller stack of another *tabBarItem*. If you want the *Second* view to be in second tab, you should add that view controller to the second tab.